# WPF data from source on a datagrid not showing up when using templated columns

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

At work we lost our team member who did all the wpf and I have picking up where he left off. This is the first time I have worked on wpf so I really don't know too much.

I have a two dimensional array of doubles that have a dynamic number of rows and columns. I want to display this as a datagrid. If I set autogeneratecolumns to true then everything works fine, except that I need the Columns to use a template I have made. 
So I handle the autogeneratingcolumn event and make a new templated column with the template I want. The problem is that now my data will not show up in the grid.
This is my datagrid.

```
<controls:DataGridEx Grid.Row="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"
                              Name="_gridIntensityMap"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                              AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IntensityMap, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                              AutoGeneratedColumns="OnAutoGeneratedIntensityMap"
                              AutoGeneratingColumn ="IntensityGridAutoGeneratingColumn">
                    </controls:DataGridEx>
```

Here is how I handle the autogeneratingcolumn event:

```
private void IntensityGridAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

            templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

            templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["IntensityNumberBoxTemplate"];
            templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["IntensityNumberBoxTemplate"];     

            // set each column to width = "1*" - causes them all to expand equally to fill space
            templateColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

            //replace the generated column with our templated one. 
            e.Column = templateColumn;
        }
```

And here is the template I am using:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IntensityNumberBoxTemplate" x:Name="IntensityNumberBoxTemplate">
            <controls:NumberBox
                    Units = "CM2"
                    ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"
                    IsReadOnly="False"
                    TextAlignment="Right" />
</DataTemplate>
```

As I said before the problem is that after using the template the data is now not showing up in the grid, the grid is blank.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about that particular data grid control you're using, but inside that DataTemplate, you should have a binding set so the NumberBox knows where to retrieve a value from.

`NumberBox` probably has a `Value` property or something on it. Set it to `Value="{Binding}"` and see how that works.

Comment: The datagrid control I am using is the same as a normal datagrid but with a few automation things tacked on. The cell does have a value property but I don't know what to bind to. My datagrid is using a DataView which is the DefaultView of a DataTable object. That object is populated with the 2d array of doubles. Not really sure how to set the binding to the right value in the DataTable.